# Getting a segmentation fault in C, dont know why?

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

I've also used Valgrind but still can't find the error. It's a CS50 problem to recover images.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage : ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //Condition to check whether the file opens or not.
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int c=0;
    FILE *img;
    char *fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    if(fileName == NULL)
    return 1;
        //Below is the dynamic reading of file.
    do
    {
        int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);
        if(arr == NULL)
        return 1;         
        fread(arr,sizeof(BYTE),512,file);
        if(arr [0] == 0xff && arr[1] == 0xd8 && arr[2] == 0xff && (arr[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if(c == 0)
            {
                img = fopen(" 000.jpg","a");// check for w or a
                fwrite(arr,sizeof(BYTE),512,img);
            }
            else 
            {
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(fileName,"%03i.jpg",c);
                img = fopen(fileName,"a");//check for w or a
                fwrite(arr,sizeof(BYTE),512,img);
            }
            c++;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(c!=0)
            {
                img = fopen(fileName,"a");
                fwrite(arr,sizeof(BYTE),512,img);
            }
        }
            free(arr);
    }while(getc(file) != EOF);
    if(img != NULL)
        fclose(file);
    fclose(img);
    free(fileName);
}
```

[screenshot with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtOgl.png)

Comment: *" Everything is irrelevant "* - that is not how you write a good question

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as gdb?

Comment: use valgrind to find memory leaks, use a debugger like gdb and read the backtrace to solve runtime errors

Comment: OT: immediately after: `FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");` should be the checking for errors, not some statements later.  So immediately after this statement should be: `if( ! file ) { perror( "fopen for input file failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  This outputs to `stderr`, your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);
        if(arr == NULL)
        return 1; `  This fails to inform the user that a problem occurred and fails to inform the user the details about the problem.  Suggest: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);
        if(arr == NULL) { perror( "malloc failed" ); fclose( file ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   Note: the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has not effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the expression: `sizeof(BYTE)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exiting out of file with feof function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886327/exiting-out-of-file-with-feof-function)

Comment: Please do not link to images.  Rather copy/paste the information as text into your question

Comment: regarding: `printf("Usage : ./recover image\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`,  not `stdout`.  Note that an executable can be any name.  Suggest: `fprintf( "USAGE: %s imagefile\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);`  this just introduces complications into your code.  suggest: `char arr[ 512 ];`   Similar considerations exist for `char *fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);` can be `char fileName[ 10 ];`

Comment: regarding: `fread(arr,sizeof(BYTE),512,file);` always check for errors when performing I/O operations.  Suggest: `if( fread(arr,sizeof(BYTE),512,file) != 512) { // handle error, cleanup, and exit }`  Similar considerations exist for all the calls to `fread()` and `fwrite()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);` and `free( arr );`  Why do this with each record read from the input file?  It is OK to use the same allocated memory over and over for the same purpose.  Also, all those calls to `malloc()` and `free()` will (tend) to fragment the available memory.

Comment: OT: regarding: `sprintf(fileName,"%03i.jpg",c);`  This only needs to be performed ONCE for each new file, not once for each 512 byte record in the file.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);` why a `int` pointer, especially as the input file is a binary file and consists of (mostly unprintable) characters

Comment: it is (usually) a good practice to not introduce a bunch of variables that contain the same information as other variables.  Suggest removing the variable: `c`,  initialize `img` to NULL, and if not NULL then some prior file needs to be closed

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code is bad. The thing you're missing is error checking. Most library functions (like `fopen`, `malloc`, etc.) indicate via their return value if they succeeded. For instance `fopen` can fail if the file you want to open does not exist.

See the [fopen documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

> Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a
> FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to
> indicate the error.

For every library call in your code, consider what happens if the function fails. You need to account for that case. The least you should do is print an error message and exit the program properly.

E.g. for `fopen`:

```c
*file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out in your code?

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*512);
```

I don't see where you're freeing it. Try this and let me know, I can help